# Merging NSArrays containing NSDictionarys

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary`s something like this:

```
myArray (
    {
    chatins = 20;
    placeImageString = 244211112265925;
},
    {
    chatins = 5;
    placeImageString = 154909144575109;
},
    {
    chatins = 30;
    placeImageString = 193867280641162;
},
    {
    chatins = 13;
    placeImageString = 224627130902;
},
```

)

and another `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary`s something like this:

```
myArray2 
(
    {
    category = "Local business";
    distance = "0.1";
    name = "Mts India";
    placeImageString = 244211112265925;
},
    {
    category = "Local business";
    distance = "0.17";
    name = "Aegis Ltd";
    placeImageString = 154909144575109;
},
    {
    category = "Automobiles and parts";
    distance = "0.19";
    name = Autopsyche;
    placeImageString = 78480207511;
},
    {
    category = Company;
    distance = "0.19";
    name = "The Oberoi, Gurgaon";
    placeImageString = 121676041233945;
},
```

)

I want to merge `myArray` and `myArray2` in order to get resulted `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary`s something like below where my `placeImageString` is the key to match the data in both arrays of dictionaries and if the key not found in `myArray2` then the value of `chatins` key should be 0.

```
myArray3 
(
{
category = "Local business";
distance = "0.1";
name = "Mts India";
placeImageString = 244211112265925;
 chatins = 20;

},
{
category = "Local business";
distance = "0.17";
name = "Aegis Ltd";
placeImageString = 154909144575109;
chatins = 5;

},
{
category = "Automobiles and parts";
distance = "0.19";
name = Autopsyche;
placeImageString = 78480207511;
chatins = 0;


},
    {
    category = Company;
    distance = "0.19";
    name = "The Oberoi, Gurgaon";
    placeImageString = 121676041233945;
    chatins = 0;

    },
)
```

Comment: Are you essentially just trying to add the "chatins" data into the myArray2 when the "placeImageString" data matches (as it looks like you have "placeImageString" already in both arrays)? Will the arrays always be aligned?

Comment: 1. yes, I am trying to add the "chatins" data into the myArray2 whenever the "placeImageString" data matches
2. what do you mean by arrays always be aligned?

Comment: I mean, above it looks as if you dont even have to compare the "placeImageString" data as the 2 arrays are (essentially) sorted to have that data already aligned (i.e. array1[0].placeImageString == array2[0].placeImageString  etc...).

Comment: Not necessarily, data may not be aligned. That's why I need to map data with `placeImageString` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have a sample code for you:

```
  NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


  NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"ABC", nil]
                                forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"NAME", nil]];
  [array1 addObject:dict];

  dict = nil;

  /*
   Same way added 2 more dictionaries to the same array - array1
   */

  NSLog(@"array1: %@", array1);


  dict = nil;

  dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
          initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"DEF", nil]
          forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"ADDRESS", nil]];

  [array2 addObject:dict];

  dict = nil;

  /*
   Same way added 2 more dictionaries to the same array - array2
   */


  NSLog(@"array2: %@", array2);


  for (int index = 0; index < [array1 count]; index ++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [array1 objectAtIndex:index];

    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict2 in array2) {

      if ([[dict1 objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:
           [dict2 objectForKey:@"ID"]]) {

        [dict1 setObject:[dict2 objectForKey:@"ADDRESS"] forKey:@"ADDRESS"];
      }
    }
  }
```

Now at the end if you check with *array1*, there is one more key (*ADDRESS*) added in all those dictionary.

Hope this help.

-Mrunal

Comment: Your second part of code is something what I wanted. It worked with few changes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Create a new empty NSMutableArray newArray
2. Loop through all NSDictionaries of myArray2

    a. Copy the current NSDictionary to a new NSMutableDictionary newDict
    b. Loop through myArray1
        b1. if myArray1.dict.placeImageString == newDict.placeImageString
            - Add myArray1.dict.chatins to newDict
            - break out of loop
    c. add newDict to newArray
```

Comment: I am doing this :: `for (int i = 0; i < mySortAry.count; i++) {
                NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
      dict1 = [mySortAry objectAtIndex:i];
      for (int j = 0; j < qbChatinArray.count; j++) {
         if ([[[qbChatinArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"placeImageString"] isEqualToString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"placeImageString"]]) {
       [dict1 setObject:[[qbChatinArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"chatins"] forKey:@"chatins"];
             }
                }
            }` but I am getting error `mutating method sent to immutable object`